# StringJoiner suffix disappears when merging

Tags: java, java-8

Please help me to understand this problem...

I'm creating a StringJoiner with suffix:

```
StringJoiner a = new StringJoiner("|\n", "", ";")
    .add("a1")
    .add("a2");

System.out.println(a.toString());
```

Output:

```
a1|
a2;
```

Now I want to merge it with another one.

```
StringJoiner b = new StringJoiner("\n")
     .add("b1")
     .merge(a)
     .add("b2");

System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Output:

```
b1
a1|
a2
b2
```

As you can see, there's no suffix of `a` anymore.

If I use `add` with `a.toString`, everything works as expected:

```
StringJoiner b = new StringJoiner("\n")
    .add("b1")
    .add(a.toString())
    .add("b2");

System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Output:

```
b1
a1|
a2;
b2
```

Did I miss something? What's the proper way to merge StringJoiners?

Comment: This is as expected. `merge()` “Adds the contents of the given `StringJoiner` without prefix and suffix as the next element if it is non-empty.” Maybe add `a.toString()` instead?

Comment: a.toString works fine. But few calls of toString look weird. The real business logic is complex and I have to perform a lot of merges. So I prefer to create a final StringJoiner and then to call toString once...

Comment: Maybe write your own string joiner class that functions the way you want? I figure it shouldn’t be too hard?

Comment: I can actually wrap it. It will solve a code readability. Not sure it's the best approach. It solves the readability issue, but I still will call toString multiple times. I'll play more with it. If I won't find the better way, probably I will follow your advice.

Comment: You can treat the suffix like a normal (last) element, `.merge(a.add(";"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as expected. From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html#merge-java.util.StringJoiner-) :

> Adds the contents of the given StringJoiner without prefix and suffix as the next element if it is non-empty. If the given StringJoiner is empty, the call has no effect.